# colored images are not occupying the tabbar item on iPhone6 & 6+

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, ios8.1

I have this code to display colored images in tabbar.

```
_itemOneNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-trophy"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
_itemOneNavigationControllerr.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-trophy-selected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

This works well on iPhone5 & 4. However, on iPhone6 & 6+, images are appearing but do not occupy the entire tabBarItem. They are appearing centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UITabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:`

```
UIImage *unselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-trophy"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage *selected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-trophy-selected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

[_itemOneNavigationController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:selected withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselected];
```